# Grabbing JSON objects and adding multiple keys values into a variable

Tags: java, json

This is an interesting one i wanted to ask what the best approach would be.

Given the json below

```
{
  "day1":2,
  "day2":1,
  "day3":4
}
```

Whats the best way of getting the sum of that?

First code i thought would be this

response = is the json above that i get

```
int value = getValue(response,name);

public static String getValue(String response,name) {
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject(response);
    Object attribute = result.get(name*);
    return attribute.toString();
}
```

Im at this point and need help. Im thinking doing a while loop but whats the best approach

Comment: `JSONObject` is not Jackson.

Comment: *"Im thinking doing a while loop"* - sounds like a good place to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this, you can get sum.

```
public static Integer getSum(String jsonStr) {

    JSONObject jsonObject = JSONObject.parseObject(jsonStr);
    Set<String> keySet = jsonObject.keySet();
    Integer sum = keySet.stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(k -> (int) jsonObject.get(k)));
    return sum;
}
```